# Contract commands not running

Tags: contract-debugging

I am trying am trying to follow [this](https://www.zastrin.com/courses/1/lessons/4-3) tutorial to build a blockchain based voting app. When I run,

```
> web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

It shows me a following in the next line,

```
...
```

Basically, the program stops executing commands after that. How to solve it?

Comment: You have ganache running, right?

Comment: @sfmiller940: No. The article doesn't write how to start ganache.

Comment: If ganache is installed, try running the command ganache-cli in another terminal window. That's your local blockchain for testing. See also [this](http://truffleframework.com/docs/ganache/using) and [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/blob/master/README.md)